# Dynamically add checkboxes to groupbox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, groupbox

i am trying to dynamically add checkboxes to a groupd box based on the amount of rows in a datatable.  when looping through i get my first result but i am not able to get the next results to show...here is my code

```
Dim q As String
    Dim qt As DataTable
    Dim gbHeight As Integer = 40
    Dim checkHG As Integer = 5
    Dim checkHN As Integer = 5


    q = "Select * from loads where filenumber = " & Shipments2.txtFileNumber.Text
    qt = GetSQL(q)


    For i = 0 To qt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim items As New List(Of LoadDetails)
        Dim ld As New LoadDetails

        items = ld.GetListBySQL("select * from loadDetails where LoadNumber = " & qt.Rows(i).Item("id"))
        For Each item As LoadDetails In items
            Dim checkgross = New CheckBox
            Dim checknet = New CheckBox
            gbHeight += 20

            'add checkbox control to form
            checkgross.Location = New Point(40, checkHG + 20)
            checkgross.Text = item.Description & " (Gross)"
            checkgross.Size = New Size(250, 20)
            checkgross.Name = item.ProductCode.ToString & "-gross"


            gbGross.Size = New Size(329, gbHeight)
            gbGross.Controls.Add(checkgross)


            rbPrintingNet.Location = New Point(rbPrintingNet.Location.X, rbPrintingNet.Location.Y + 40)

            checknet.Location = New Point(40, checkHN + 20)
            checknet.Text = item.Description & " (Net)"
            checknet.Size = New Size(250, 20)
            checknet.Name = item.ProductCode.ToString & "-net"

            gbNet.Location = New Point(44, rbPrintingNet.Location.Y + 25)
            gbNet.Size = New Size(329, gbHeight)
            gbNet.Controls.Add(checknet)

            Me.Size = New Size(Me.Size.Width, Me.Size.Height + 50)


        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

All your controls are on directly top of each other:

```
checkgross.Location = New Point(40, checkHG + 20)
```

Since `checkHG` never changes.  Change the Location() for each dynamic control...

Comment: You could just add a docked **FlowLayoutPanel** inside your GroupBox so that you don't need to worry about explicitly setting the Location() of each dynamic control.